# ORA-01722: invalid number in Update query

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have following query and getting `ORA-01722: invalid number`

```
UPDATE SCHEDULE SET IS_ACTIVE = 0 WHERE REMINDER_ID IN ( SELECT replace('1,2', '''', '') as xtx FROM DUAL);
```

When I tried following way it executes , `SELECT replace('1,2', '''', '')  FROM DUAL;`
I am getting (1,2) but this is not happening in the first query.

Comment: that is not doing what you think it is.  You are getting a string, "1,2" not two separate numeric values.

Comment: @OldProgrammer how can I update table with this ? any other way ?

Comment: where do the values 1,2 come from?  Is is really a string with two numbers?  You need to provide more detail

Comment: @OldProgrammer its from server. I am getting this value as string from server to my SP for eg: "'12,13,14'"

Comment: @OldProgrammer see My answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it and working - x_reminder_id = "'12,13'"

```
   MERGE INTO SCHEDULE dst
  USING (
    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(x_reminder_id,        '\d+', 1, LEVEL) AS id
    FROM   DUAL
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LEAST(
                          REGEXP_COUNT(x_reminder_id,        '\d+')
                        )
  ) src
  ON (src.id = dst.REMINDER_ID)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE
      SET IS_ACTIVE = 0;
```